# Why does Android Wi-Fi Direct only return one service at a time with discoverServices?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

When you call `discoverPeers` in Wi-Fi Direct, it returns a list of peers to the `onPeersAvailable` method in the `PeerListListener` (once you call `requestPeers`). However, when you call `discoverServices`, you only get one service at a time to the `onDnsSdServiceAvailable` method in the `DnsSdServiceResponseListener`. Does anyone know if there is a way to change this and get all services available at a given time? Or if there is a particular reason why it can only return one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no ways on changing this. They are just given one by one, and the timing is not really set either.

All and all, the suggested way on handling getting them all is to implement a timer, which is reset every time you get a discovery, and it is fires before it gets discovery, you would determine that all peer services have been discovered. Sucks, but that's the way it works.

Comment: To add to this answer, I think the logic by the Android developers is correct.  The device has discovered a service, so your application is notified of this newly discovered service. However, when the PeerListListener callback is called, the onPeerAvailable method is providing you with the state of all available peers.  Wi-Fi P2P service discovery has a timeout of two minutes (https://sphen.proxmobil.com/android-wi-fi-direct-service-discovery/), so you could simply cache discovered services for that two minute period.